# Unable to use function while monitoring folder

Tags: vbscript, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor a specific folder, for a file creation using VBS.

This is the monitor creation function of the folder, as I've seen in many examples:

```
Function CreateMonitor(path)
    Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    path = Split(fso.GetAbsolutePathName(path), ":")
    drv  = path(0) & ":"
    dir  = Replace(path(1), "\", "\\")
    If Right(dir, 2) <> "\\" Then dir = dir & "\\"

    query = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent" & _
            " WITHIN " & Interval & _
            " WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile'" & _
            " AND TargetInstance.Drive='" & drv & "'" & _
            " AND TargetInstance.Path='" & dir & "'"

    Set CreateMonitor = wmi.ExecNotificationQuery(query)
End Function
```

Then I save it to the following var:

```
Set monitor = CreateMonitor(FolderPath)
```

Eventually I use the following loop which will run endlessly (monitor) and will create an instance when a file in the folder was created :

```
Do
    Set evt = monitor.NextEvent()   

    Select Case evt.Path_.Class
        Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
            Call SendNotification (evt.TargetInstance)
    End Select
Loop
```

After a successful monitoring process creation I'm willing to move further with the file that has been created and send it to "SendNotification" function.

The problem is that the calling of the function doesn't occurs and I'm finding myself stuck in the loop without entering this function. It waits until a file is being created and only then proceed further.

What am I doing wrong? Whats is the proper way for a function call in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> **Return value** If the NextEvent method is successful, it returns an SWbemObject object that contains the requested event. If the call
>   times out, the returned object is NULL and an error is raised.
>
> **Error codes** Upon the completion of the NextEvent method, the Err object may contain the error code in the following list.
>
> **wbemErrTimedOut** - 0x80043001 Requested event did not arrive in the amount of time specified in iTimeoutMs

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393711(v=vs.85).aspx

Said that, I would try `If evt Is Nothing Then Exit Loop` as follows

```
Do
  Set evt = monitor.NextEvent()   

  If evt Is Nothing Then Exit Do

  Select Case evt.Path_.Class
         Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
              call SendNotification (evt.TargetInstance)
  End Select
Loop
```

Or

```
On Error Resume Next

Do
  Set evt = monitor.NextEvent()   

  If Err <> 0 Then
      If Err.Number = wbemErrTimedout Then ' = &H80043001
         Exit Do

  Select Case evt.Path_.Class
         Case "__InstanceCreationEvent"
              call SendNotification (evt.TargetInstance)
  End Select
Loop
```